# Сервер не реагирует на запрос браузера при переходе по страницам

Tags: node.js, url, express, маршрутизация

Есть сервер на Node.JS+Express.js. Никак не могу поймать get-запрос , который отправляет браузер при загрузке страницы.

Вот код сервера. Очень сырой и не приведен в порядок.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const session = require('express-session')
const dbConnection = require('./database') 
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
const passport = require('./passport')
const url = require('url')
const app = express()
const PORT = 5000
const router = express.Router()
// Route requires
const user = require('./routes/user')


// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
)
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Sessions
app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'secret', //pick a random string to make the hash that is generated secure
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: dbConnection }),
        resave: false, //required
        saveUninitialized: false //required
    })
)

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session()) // calls the deserializeUser


// Routes
var siteUrls = [
    {pattern:'^/login/?$', user: false}
, {pattern:'^/logout$', user: true}
, {pattern:'^/home/$', user: false}
, {pattern:'^/home/\\w+/?$', user: false}
, {pattern:'^/users/\\w+/?$', user: true}
, {pattern:'^/signup$', user: false}
, {pattern:'^/profile$', user: true}
, {pattern:'^/chat$', user: true}
, {pattern:'^/search$', user: true}
, {pattern:'^/dating$', user: true}
]

function authorizeUrls(urls) {
    function authorize(req, res, next) {
        var requestedUrl = url.parse(req.url).pathname
        for (var ui in urls) {
            var pattern = urls[ui].pattern
            var restricted = urls[ui].user
            console.log("KUKU", requestedUrl , "===", pattern, requestedUrl.match(pattern))
            if (requestedUrl.match(pattern)) {
                if (restricted) {
                    if (req.session.authorized) {
                        // если все хорошо, просто переходим к следующим правилам
                        next()
                        return
                    }
                    else{
                        // пользователь не авторизирован, отправляем его на страницу логина
                        res.writeHead(303, {'Location': '/login'})
                        res.end()
                        return
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (!req.session.authorized) {
                        console.log("KULKU")
                        next()
                        return
                    } else {
                        res.writeHead(303, {'Location': '/profile'})
                        res.end()
                        return
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        // сюда мы попадаем, только если в цикле не нашлось совпадений
        console.log('common 404 for ', req.url)
        res.end('404: there is no ' + req.url + ' here')
    }
    return authorize 
}

app.use('/', authorizeUrls(siteUrls))

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('===== upsser!!======')

})

app.use('/home', user)

// Starting Server 
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on PORT: ${PORT}`)
})
```

И проблема как раз в том что обычные запросы , которые я отправляю с помощью axios или fetch сервер видит. А запрос при закрузке страницы по url-адресу он не видит.

Comment: Вы 5000 порт в адрес добавляете?

Comment: @Suvitruf , в package.json установлен прокси , который перенаправляет все запросы с 3000 порта на 5000.

Comment: Покажите, какой адрес вы открываете в браузере.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/ после "/" может быть любой адрес.

Comment: А прокси точно правильно работает? localhost:5000 не открывается?

Comment: да точно. Потому как запросы с fetch сервер видит (они тоже отсылают на 3000-й порт)

Comment: localhost:5000 не открывается